# APIM Request URL Optional Path

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

I'm using APIM to ingest data from an external service (pointing to a Logic app HTTP request of course, using POST method). The service has dynamic URLs that are passed to my APIM API continuously in a loop.

For instance it will send me a dynamic URL such as `baseurl/one` then `baseurl/one/two`, all in one loop that it tries to pass to my APIM.

The issue is that the APIM front end does not accept optional parameters to the template parameters (`baseurl/{one}/{two}`). They have to be required. I tried opening in OpenAPI editor and when I set the parameter to false. It tells me it only allows me to set to be true.

[image]
[image]

So when APIM sees the `baseurl/one`, it errors the service because APIM requires the`{two}` parameter. Is there a way via policy to have APIM ignore the `{two}` optional parameter?

I have tried using the `<path segment="/optionalPath" />` inside a condition to check the URL segment length, but APIM doesn't allow it apparently. Or even check if `{par2}` is set then require it otherwise just use `{one}`?

Comment: You can make use of query parameters, it has required check box

Comment: As per https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/2.0.md#fixed-fields-7, path parameters will always be required. You can define two separate operations one like baseurl/{one} and baseurl/{one}/{two}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The issue is that the APIM front end does not accept optional parameters to the template parameters (`baseurl/{one}/{two}`). They have to be required. I tried opening in OpenAPI editor and when I set the parameter to false. It tells me it only allows me to set to be true.

Yes, template/path parameters are required and AFAIK, we can't define them as optional in APIM.

[image]

Either you can take the parameters as Query parameter to accept the value optionally with the help of **Required** checkbox.

[image]

Or you can add them as a separate operations like below.

***Added the API***-

[image]

***Then added all the Operations in it***-

[image]

[image]

Comment: two questions. 1) Isn't query parameters go in the URL as: baseurl?par1=value? If so, the service doesn't send it the URL parameter that way. 2) Did you add the query parameters in "All Operations" tab as you added both in one screenshot, so I can assume you did, making sure it wasn't at each individual operation.

Comment: @AnalyzingTasks yes, query parameters will look like baseurl?par1=value but in my answer I am not adding them as query parameters, I am adding separate operations per parameter and here these parameters are added as a template parameter

Comment: In the screenshots, I have added two different operations one called `First Operation` and second called `Second Operation`. If you will try it, you will get to see that here parameters are added as template parameter

Comment: Ok I was under the impression from the second screenshot (where **Query** tab is highlighted) that you had tested it with that method. But, the first / second operation worked as you suggested! Thank you for your insight on APIM.